# ActionMailer testing ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, actionmailer

Can't figure out why the `bundle exec rake test` command fails but when I manually try to send the email it works and displays as it should.

Error message:
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) and it highlights 
`def stock_alert_email(stock)` from `user_mailer.rb`

`user_mailer.rb`

```
def stock_alert_email(stock)
    @stock = stock
    mail(to: 'email@email.org', subject: "Stock Alert! %s has reached %s" % [@stock[0].to_s, @stock[1].to_s])
end
```

`user_mailer_test.rb`

```
test "stock_alert_email" do
  email = UserMailer.stock_alert_email().deliver_now
  assert_not ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.empty?

  # Test the body of the sent email contains what we expect it to
  assert_equal ['email@email.org'], email.from
  assert_equal ['email@email.org'], email.to
  assert_equal "Stock Alert! %s has reached %s" % [@stock[0].to_s, @stock[1].to_s], email.subject
  assert_equal read_fixture('stock_alert_email').join, email.body.to_s
end
```

`where I call the mail to send`

```
UserMailer.stock_alert_email(@stock).deliver_now
```

When I use binding.pry before the above^^ line I see that @stock is

```
[1] pry(main)> @stock
=> ["AAPL", 114.21]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here in this line

```
email = UserMailer.stock_alert_email().deliver_now
```

You are not passing any argument to the `stock_alert_email` while it expects an argument.